# How to rewrite this css for IE

Tags: css

I have this css code which is only supported in Firefox.

```
/* Green header */
.container {
    background: linear-gradient(#5FA309, #3B8018);
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 20px 0 10px;
    width: 270px;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #264400;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
}

.container:after {
    content: '';
    background: linear-gradient(top left, #5FA309, #3B8018);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#5FA309), to(#3B8018));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top left,  #5FA309,  #3B8018);
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px; right: -7px;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

How I can make this code also supported on IE? I want to use only css without images.

Comment: I want to support it for the latest IE version.

Comment: You sure? IE10 is the latest version, but half of IE user still uses IE8. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer#Desktop_Market_share_by_year_and_version

Comment: This code will be used for internal web site. The old version is not a problem. I prefer to use the latest IE.

Comment: for ie 9 and 10 I believe the webkit is `-ms-liniear-gradient();` But for ie 6-8 I think you want a `filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=0,StartColor=#FF0000,EndColor=#00FF00);` [microsoft gradients](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532997(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @PeterPenzov: From what I looked up, your current CSS should work with IE10.

Comment: @nhahtdh I tested the code on IE 9 - It's not working properly.

Comment: @PeterPenzov: The problem is with your definition of latest version - latest is IE10.

Comment: Always *always* place the unprefixed version of a property or value *after* all of the prefixed versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the use of the `-ms-` vendor prefix and the order in which vendor prefixes are set:

```
.container{
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #5fa309), color-stop(1, #3b8018));
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #5fa309 0%, #3b8018 100%);
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #5fa309 0%, #3b8018 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #5fa309 0%, #3b8018 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #5fa309 0%, #3b8018 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(top, #5fa309 0%, #3b8018 100%);
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0 20px 0 10px;
    width:270px;
    line-height:20px;
    font-size:12px;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    text-shadow:0 1px 0 #264400;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#fff
}
.container:after{
    content:'';
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0, #5fa309), color-stop(1, #3b8018));
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top left, #5fa309 0%, #3b8018 100%);
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top left, #5fa309 0%, #3b8018 100%);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top left, #5fa309 0%, #3b8018 100%);
    background:-ms-linear-gradient(top left, #5fa309 0%, #3b8018 100%);
    background:linear-gradient(top left, #5fa309 0%, #3b8018 100%);
    position:absolute;
    top:3px;
    right:-7px;
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(45deg);
    transform:rotate(45deg)
}
```

Comment: Would you not require the wc3 standard of `gradient` and `linear-gradient` declared before the webkits? just something I've heard.

Comment: No, think of the order of the vendor prefixes as `if` statements. If the user is on webkit, render the `-webkit-` prefixed properties, and so on, else, if the user is using a browser that supports the standard, set the properties on the standard prefix. Here's an interesting article explaining it: http://css-tricks.com/ordering-css3-properties/

Comment: That's what I thought originally! But I'd been told otherwise :S thanks for clearing that up :) lol

Comment: I tested your code on IE 10. It's working very well. Thank you!